# Can autopilot navigate automatically?

Tags: autopilot, airbus

When the pilots enter their flight plan into the FMGS, the route will be shown on the ND. Can the autopilot automatically turn when needed with the given plan, or the pilots have to manually adjust the heading everytime?
And if possible how do they can manually turn the aircraft within autopilot when needed like: landing, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking (not specific to Airbus), what the layman refers to as "autopilot" is actually three logical systems:

1. The Flight Management System (FMS), which  figures out where the plane is in relation to the supplied flight plan.
2. The Flight Director (FD), which figures out how to navigate the plane to where the FMS wants it *or according to manual inputs*.
3. The Autopilot (AP), which manipulates the flight controls to follow the FD.

Generally, the FMS and FD will be engaged for the entire flight, but the AP is not engaged until after takeoff and is disengaged shortly before landing.

While the flight plan is issued before takeoff, it is frequently amended by ATC during flight. When this happens, the pilot just enters the new data into the FMS and lets the FD and AP adjust as needed.

However, sometimes ATC will issue "vectors" to aircraft, which is an instruction to fly a particular heading or track. To comply, the pilot dials that setting into the FD control knob and changes modes so it follows that manual input instead of the FMS. When ATC puts them back on course, the pilots simply switch the FD back to following the FMS.

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged [airbus](/questions/tagged/airbus), I will answer for the A320. The following image from the [FCOM](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A320-Autoflight.html) shows the **FCU (Flight Control Unit)** on the glareshield:

[image: FCU]

This is where all inputs for the autopilot are made. The second knob is the HDG OR TRK SELECTOR KNOB, which allows setting a heading. In general these knobs work as follows:

[image: Philosophy]

To make the autopilot follow the flight plan from the **FMGS**, you *push the knob in*. If you want to manually deviate, you *pull the knob out*, the dashes will disappear and show a number and you rotate the knob to adjust.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, RNAV autopilots can fly a given route automatically. A pilot can disengage and fly by hand at any time during the flight and the flick of a switch.

Comment: Sometime during approach, the pilots turn the aircraft heading from the FCU. What will  they do to override the RNAV?

Comment: turn the autopilot off and use the stick, or go from RNAV to Heading mode and give the autopilot a heading to fly.