# What is that A340 cockpit panel on the glareshield?

Tags: flight-instruments, cockpit, feature-identification, airbus-a340

I want to know the panel's name and how it works. This picture is an Iberia Airbus A340-600
[image]

Answer (score 4):

That display is part of the AFS (Auto Flight System) Control Panel on the FCU (Flight Control Unit):

[image: A340 FCU]
<sup>([Airbus A340 FCOM - Auto Flight](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/FCOM_A340-Auto_Flight.pdf) - General)</sup>

The general idea of the FCU is that you can push in the knobs, which will put the respective autoflight mode in an automatic setting (called *managed mode*) and show dashes in the display, and you can pull the knobs out and then rotate them to manually overwrite values (called *selected mode*).

In your example, the display currently shows:

- **SPD 250**: The autothrust system is maintaining a manually selected speed of 250 knots.
- **HDG ---⚫**: The lateral autopilot mode is in managed mode, meaning the aircraft will follow the flight plan programmed into the FMGS. See also [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/70789/33692).
- **ALT 08000**: The current target altitude for the autopilot is 8000 feet.
- **V/S -1000**: The vertical autopilot mode is to maintain a manually selected descent of 1000 feet per minute.

The FCU allows you to switch between selecting a heading (HDG) vs. a track (TRK) and a vertical speed (V/S) vs. a flight path angle (FPA) with the button at the center. The **HDG** and **V/S** in the center of the display mean that the current mode is in heading and vertical speed.

Comment: thank you very much